# How to wait for a shell to be closed from another shell in swt?

Tags: java, shell, user-interface, swt

I'm creating a program in SWT. I have a first Shell that has on it the "add user" button.
When you click on the button, a second shell appear.
In this case the first shell is still cliccable and focusable. I cannot understand how to avoid that the first shell is focusable until the second has been closed.

This behavior is the default behavior of the dialogs, but I want to have the same behavior with shells. Do you know how can I obtain that?

The code I use to open the second shell is this:

```
Display display = Menu.this.getDisplay();
AddEditUser shell = new AddEditUser(display);
shell.open();
shell.layout();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Thankyou

I follow your suggestions, and now the behavior is ok, but now the second shell does not have the top bar as shown in the picture.
[image: window without top bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL` or `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` for second shells style

[image]

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class ShellTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Button b = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("Open Shell");
        b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                openNewShell(shell);
            }
        });
        shell.setSize(250, 150);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    protected static void openNewShell(final Shell shell) 
    {
        Shell child = new Shell(shell, SWT.TITLE|SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL| SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MAX);
        child.setSize(100, 100);
        child.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        child.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        child.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: but now I cannot see the top bar. see the picture I added above.

Comment: @hurtledown: See the updated answer. Specially the child shells constructor. Also, I would suggest you to play with different swt style bits to get a feel of them.

Answer (score 2):

Open the second shell with the style `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL`